# Запуск MySQL в Ubuntu через сокет

Tags: mysql, база-данных, ubuntu

Не могу запустить mysql в терминале через сокет, т.е. вот так:

```
mysql -u root
```

Возникает следующая ошибка:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through
socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

Через сеть все получается:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u root -p
```

В чем может быть дело ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам нужно сообщить серверу и mysql-клиентам, что они будут общаться исключительно через сокет. Для этого, нужно открыть конфигурационный файл my.cnf и прописать путь к сокету в директиве `socket` в двух секциях: [client] - для клиентов и в [mysqld] - для сервера (если этих директив нет, добавьте)

```
[client]
...
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
...
[mysqld]
...
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
...
```

После этого следует перезагрузить сервер

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

и убедиться, что в папке /var/run/mysqld/ появился файла сокета. Не советую располагать файл в /tmp, так как от туда он может регулярно удаляться по cron-заданиям очистки и вы снова и снова будете сталкиваться с этой ошибкой (каталог /var/run собственно и предназначен для сокетов и pid-файлов).

Если вы планируете работать через сокет, то можно вообще запретить сетевой доступ, даже локально. Для этого нужно в секции [mysqld] конфигурационного файла my.cnf установить директиву `skip-networking`

```
[mysqld]
...
skip-networking
```